# Vaadin vs jQuery UI

Tags: jquery, vaadin

I'm starting a new Java project and it seems to me that the most prevailing UI technologies are jQuery UI vs Vaadin (or GWT).

Is there any guidelines on how to choose the most appropriate UI framework, any advantages and advantages that can be noted here.

For example using Vaadin is like developing a desktop application comparable to developing Java Swing applications which different to using jQuery.

But I would appreciate any additional thoughts regarding this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know Vaadin, I know Java, programmed a little in GWT and I know jQuery quite well. So here is my 2 cents about it:

Bottom line is - I find it much easier to develop client side GUI with pure HTML/jQuery.

1. GWT promises support for all browsers, jQuery does it too.
2. GWT enables you to use a familiar language (java) instead of learning a new one (jQuery) - here we can debate, but if you are also familiar with jQuerythen this is not really an advantage, if not, then i think learning jQuery is much easier then learning GWT framework.
3. I think GWT adds a lot of unnecessary complexity to a project (new compiler, new set of SDKs, new errors, new way for debugging).
4. There are great tools for debugging javascript/ajax and when using GWT you mostly unable to use them. You'll have to use Eclipse debug mechanism which might be a bit cumbersome.
5. Deploying changes in GWT take much more time then regular HTML/javascript project, this means longer development time.
6. If you are using another FW in your application (like Spring, Hibernate), mixing them with GWT FW can create a coding/maintenance hell (I'm talking from experience).

Like I said, I don't know Vaadin, so I can't comment on that, but I strongly suggest you at least give jQuery a shot.

Comment: Thanks, I know jQuery pretty well and still learning Vaadin, I agree with the pints you state however Vaadin applications -in my opinion- look so much smoother and better than jQuery applications. Here I ask isn't that worth the extra complexity.

Comment: Like i said i don't know it very well, so i can't argue on that, but consider development and maintenance time and see if it is worth the trade-off. Also consider jquery community is huge, this means that solving problems is easier and if you need new functinality, someone probably already written a plugin for that.

Comment: The main thing i don't like about these sort of FW, is that they take the control from you, but that's just me :). Also, try to figure out how easy/hard it is to deviate from their template (i.e., replace button image, change layout etc.).

Comment: Vaadin provides the ability to set the CSS class a component should have -done in the Java code side- and in the application CSS file you can style it in the appropriate way. I haven't gone too deep into it but that seems pretty good integration to me.

Comment: If you're considering a pure client-side approach, you'll want to use `JAX-RS` server-side. Consider using `backbone.js` and `html5boilerplate` to simplify your client side dev.

Comment: @fatman: Vaadin is not GWT.  It has several advantages over GWT, especially regarding development/deployment time, complexity, and debugging.  Most of your arguments do not apply to Vaadin.

Answer (score 5):

What I like about Vaadin is that it handles the whole client side stuff and the communication between the client and the server (keep the UI refreshed and so forth). As you already mentioned it's like programming a Swing application.
Vaadin gives you a bunch of components and is extendable with GWT widgets. It's still adaptable.

You don't have to care about HTML and JavaScript with Vaadin so you can fully concentrate developing your application.

I hope I could've helped you with my point of view.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery UI is at too low level to be just used alone(I would not do that, it wont solve your UI problems), did you see what twitter bootstrap could do? it has all the stuff jQuery UI basically has and many usuful plugins / components - it is actual framework to build upon and only UI framework what I will be using at least few years from now if im developing something to web. (responsive design possibilities etc. ;) - just pointing this opinion out, even though you didnt include it to your question: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/

What comes to vaadin and GWT, I as an already experienced web programmer dont feel need for "desktop application kind of web programming" , it would only confuse me more so I would not use them until I make some sort of "desktop software look-a-like" pages to web. (and btw. if they are anything similar to swing, they would be nightmare, but like said - havent used, because i dont need them.).

Comment: Sure, the nature of the application should be an important deciding factor here. I like twitter bootstrap, looks nice, however I only have time to use ready components to solve business problems and no time to extend a framework to make it look better.

Answer (score 1):

If you know JavaScript and jQuery (much) better than Java I would suggest you to use jQuery UI.  Otherwise I would suggest you to use vaadin.  Both frameworks have their advantages and disadvantages and it's very much a personal preference whether you like one more than the other one (e.g. preference for typed / untyped languages).

First of all I think both frameworks have a big community and a lot of plug-ins.  So far I could always find the add-ons I needed for my work.

Some advantages of vaadin:

- you can use one language (Java) for your RIA
- development is type safe -> reduces main source for errors
- you can develop your application like a desktop application

  - don't have to deal with client side code (JavaScript, jQuery)
  - don't have to deal with client-server communication (AJAX)
- easier to write secure applications since the whole webapp state is stored on the server (client side manipulations are useless)
- you can debug your whole code directly in your IDE
- access your database in an object-oriented fashion using the Java Persistence API (hibernate and co.)

Some disadvantages of vaadin:

- initial set up of the project (with webapp reload scripts, debugger setup) takes more time than for a simple php/javascript project
- deployment time is a bit longer (~5 seconds to reload the webapp)
- to use external JS components you need to write a Java wrappers first; however this is not that hard (see https://vaadin.com/blog/-/blogs/vaadin-7-loves-javascript-components)
- Vaadin is a high-level framework that uses GWT in background.  Thus adapting specific details in vaadin's components is not as easy as in a JavaScript based UI framework

Answer (score 0):

Creating a UI in Vaadin seems a lot simpler than creating a UI in javascript + HTML -- regardless of framework.